# How can I make Capybara use Routing helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using rails 3, Steak & Capybara. I have restful resources, is it possible to use routing helpers available to views and controllers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec and named routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just have to put this on your spec_helper.rb

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

inside the configuration definition block, that is, the one that is wrapped by:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
# All your config.include calls go here.
end
```

And then you can use it on your feature specs:

```
scenario "Show school" do
school = School.create!(:name => "Pablo de Olavide")
visit(school_path(school))
save_and_open_page
page.has_content?("Pablo de Olavide").should == true
end
```

Do not use:

```
include ActionController::UrlWrite
```

As it is deprecated in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this to get it working with Rails 4.1.6:

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers if defined? Rails
```

Comment: You could put it in `rails_helper.rb` without the conditional.