# Rspec and named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm quite new to rails, and trying to follow the railstutorial. Everything goes fine, except for my tests which can't get past the named routes (5.3.3)

My routes.rb :

```rb
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

 resources :users
 match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

 match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
 match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
 match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'

 root to: 'static_pages#home'

 #Commented stuff
```

My firsts tests (spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb) :

```rb
describe "Static pages" do

subject { page }

shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: heading) }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title(page_title)) }
end

describe "Home page" do
  before { visit root_path }
  let(:heading)    { 'Sample App' }
  let(:page_title) { 'Home' }

  it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
end

#Other tests
```

The spec_helper.rb looks like (without all the commented stuff)

```rb
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

The errors I get from rspec are all like this one :

```rb
 Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000004a12210>
 Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:17
 # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I already tried using

```rb
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

in the spec_helper, but it changed my errors to

```rb
 Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
 # /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185
```

I also tried different way of renaming my routes, but none of them worked. I'm back to the tutorial version.

If it can be of any help in finding what exactly is a problem, I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, with rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.2p290. Hope you can help, I spend quite a while googling for a solution and didn't find any ^^'

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Named routes should work if you put the following in rspec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

Is that how you set it up?

Comment: It is exactly what I did, except for the 'config.' part. Everything works perfectly now ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: In case anyone makes it this far and is still stumped, it's also worth noting that root_path (etc) only works within the "do...end" block of an "it" section within a "describe" block of the RSpec tests. So if you created functions to handle "it" sections based on a path parameter passed to the function, you can't pass root_path (etc) as a parameter to said function.

Comment: This also fixed my issue of Rails 4.2 deprecastion warning `DEPRECATION WARNING: named_routes.helpers is deprecated, please use route_defined?(route_name) to see if a named route was defined` so now I have clean rspec logs until I wait for the https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/1142 to be released.

Comment: I think you mean `rails_helper.rb`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have access to named routes inside of your rspec controller specs.  You could however just do visit('/'), which is the equivalent of root_path.

Comment: Thanks, it works well and make my tests go green ! However, the tutorial seems to use named routes [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#code:static_pages_spec_shared_example) and I'm curious to know how ^^

Comment: Your welcome just upvote and accept the answer then please! :)

Comment: Upvote requires 15 reputation, sorry ! I will wait a bit before accepting it, in case of someone actually knows how to make it work 'as in the book' :)

Answer (score 3):

Google brought me here, even my error message doesn't fit 100%.

In my case Capybara command `visit`is unknown...

Error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa49a73c>
```

Since Capybara 2.0 one has to use folder `spec/features` capybara commands don't work in folder `spec/requests` anymore.

That helped me:
http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

Hope you find this usefull.

Answer (score 2):

You should have used

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

instead of

```
rspec --init
```

and you wouldn't have had to modify the config file.

Don't do it now though or your application will break and you'll have to waste some more time figuring out why it broke.

Comment: But your comment really isn't a solution. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with the same Tutorial.  It turns out that I needed to just restart the Spork service, and all worked fine.

The solution posted by Tom L worked for me, but when I removed that line and restarted Spork, that also fixed the problem.

Hope that helps out any other people who are wary about deviating from the tutorial's code!

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Tom L's code did not work for me. So it is Spork's fault afterall! I spent my whole afternoon looking for a solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Named routes should work if you put the following in **rails_helper.rb** not the spec_helper.rb:

checkout at my rails_helper.rb code

```rb
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
if Rails.env.production?
  abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!')
end
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```