# Capybara 2.0.0.beta4 has undefined paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

I just upgraded to Capybara 2.0.0.beta4 with rspec-rails 2.11.4 and I moved my request spec (I only have one) to `spec/features` as advised by the [Capybara-Readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Capybara.md) in the RSpec-Rails repository.
When I run the tests now it does not find any paths. So for the following test block:

```
it "should be able to access the signup page through the front page" do
  visit root_path
  click_link "Signup For Free Now"
  page.should have_content("Signup")
end
```

I get the error message:

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec...>
```

When I try to run the test with `visit "/"` it works fine. Other gem versions are:

- rails 3.2.1
- rspec 2.11.0
- rack-test 0.6.2

Any ideas for a reason for the path problem?

Comment: The named routes can also be added if you aren't using rspec: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running "bundle update rspec-rails" to get version 2.12.0 solved the same issue for me.