# Passing a named route to a controller macro in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to DRY up my RSpec examples by adding a few controller macros for frequently used tests. In this somewhat simplified example, I created a macro that simply tests whether getting the page results in a direct to another page:

```
def it_should_redirect(method, path)
  it "#{method} should redirect to #{path}" do
    get method
    response.should redirect_to(path)
  end
end
```

I'm trying to call it like so:

```
context "new user" do
  it_should_redirect 'cancel', account_path
end
```

When I run the test I get an error saying that it doesn't recognize account_path:

> undefined local variable or method `account_path' for ... (NameError)

I tried including Rails.application.routes.url_helpers per the guidance given in [this SO thread on named routes in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes) but still receive the same error.

How can I pass a named route as a parameter to a controller macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url helpers included with `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` are valid only within examples (blocks set with `it` or `specify`). Within example group (context or describe) you cannot use it. Try to use symbols and `send` instead, something like

```
# macro should be defined as class method, use def self.method instead of def method
def self.it_should_redirect(method, path)
  it "#{method} should redirect to #{path}" do
    get method
    response.should redirect_to(send(path))
  end
end

context "new user" do
  it_should_redirect 'cancel', :account_path
end
```

Don't forget to include url_helpers to config.

Or call the macro inside example:

```
def should_redirect(method, path)
  get method
  response.should redirect_to(path)
end

it { should_redirect 'cancel', account_path }
```