# named route as a parameter for example group in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, helper

I am newbie in testing and using RSpec and need some help:

I have shared example group:

```
shared_examples_for 'request which do something' do |opts = {}|
  respond.should redirect_to(opts[:redirect_to])
end
```

In my spec file:

```
describe "behavior" do
  it_should_behave_like 'request which do something', :redirect_to => root_path
end
```

Looks great, but I get this error:

```
Exception encountered: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Class:0x000000069e2838>>
```

and it points on line with 'it_should_behave_like ... '

I tried to include **Rails.application.routes.url_helper** in spec_helper, but it doesn't work anyway.

By the way it perfectly works from example like this:

```
describe "behavior" do
  it "should redirect" do
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

(even without explicit including url_helpers)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use path helpers within example groups, but there is a workaround. See this answer:

[Passing a named route to a controller macro in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305293/passing-a-named-route-to-a-controller-macro-in-rspec)

With this, you can pass a symbol and use `send`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I thought about it too, but was afraid that I miss something and there is another way.
I appreciate your rapid answer! Thanks again.

Comment: One *can* use path helpers in example groups. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In example groups, write `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path`
instead of just `root_path`. You could create your own helper method to
make repeated calls short.