# Rspec 3.0.0 Update Ruby on Rails falling tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I used `gem 'rspec-rails'` (all tests passed) and I updated it to `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'` and now almost all my tests fail, e.g.:

```
rspec ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:60 # languages index
```

My test look like:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "languages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_title('EduWords') }
    it { should have_content("Toggle navigation EduWords Home Sign up Log in Authors Back to Top EduWords © MiDaS Project 2014") }

  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

`config/routes`

```
Eduwords::Application.routes.draw do
  get "authors/index"
  get "mainpage/index"
  resources :tags

  resources :languages

  resources :words

  resources :tests

  resources :users

  get "sessions/new"
  get "users/new"

  get "download", to: "words#download", as: 'download'

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root :to => "mainpage#index"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
end
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the test failure?

Comment: 24) LanguagesController routing languages routes to languages#new
     Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/languages/new").to route_to("languages#new")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `route_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LanguagesController_2::RoutingLanguages:0x00000002de4f98>
     # ./spec/routing/languages_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: That’s not the failing spec for the test you put in the answer.

Comment: Sorry: 34) languages index 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Languages_2::Index:0x00000002cd5d78>
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: What’s in your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: ok now I have only error like: rspec ./spec/routing/languages_routing_spec.rb:6 # LanguagesController routing languages routes to languages#new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like RSpec isn't finding your route_helper methods (e.g. `root_path`).  Here's an answer to that question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476576/2231608

> Named routes should work if you put the following in rspec_helper.rb:

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

> Is that how you set it up?