# Testing nested rails route with :path => ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, controller

In my routes.rb I have

```
resources :users, :path => '', param: :name do
  resources :locations
end
```

This gives me my URLs exactly like I want them, e.g. http://example.com/julian/locations

However, I just can't figure out, how to test them. I ran over this, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

```
setup do
  @location = locations(:one)
  @user = users(:one)
end

test "should get index" do
  get :index, user_id: @user.name
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:locations)
end
```

Can someone point me into the right direction? Or is there a better (and testable) way, to achieve my URL-pattern?

Comment: Did you try using path helpers? (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) e.g. `users_path(@user.name)` instead of `get`.

Comment: As I understand, the path- and url-helpers are only available in controllers and views, @brito

Comment: Also, you could (should?) use RSpec, then you would be able to use path helpers (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes)). I'd say using rspec would be better and more testable than what you're doing :)

Comment: I'll have a look at RSpec, thx!