# Access the routes from helpers Rspec for engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2, rspec3

I am trying access the routes from helpers rspec for Engine
Tried something 
**expect(:get => "routes_path").to route_to(:controller => "name")".**

but failed with NoMethodError: Undefined method `routes_path

After searching a lot, what i know is routes can be accessed through controllers and tested. But can it be done from helpers as well?

Comment: Is `routes_path` something you can access from your typical helper context, i.e. the view?

Comment: why would you have something called `routes_path`? Do you an endpoint called `/routes`?

Comment: Ya.. i have an endpoint  `.. /routes `.  `routes_path` gives the `/routes` path but how to test in helper if it is routed properly. I have an alternative option but testing the path ` allow(helper).to receive(:routes).and_return(routes)`

Comment: And then test for path if both paths are same. But i want to know if it can be testing the `routes` .

Answer (score 0):

Having this in your Rspec config might work for that

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes) question.

You could also try using the actual path and controller#action.

Something like:

```
expect(get("path/to/routes")).to route_to("your_controller#action")
```